# Web starter kit gulp error on first install

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp

trying out WSK, I just followed instructions on google dev website, this is my error after a $ gulp or $ gulp serve:

```
/folderpath/web-starter-kit-master/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:46
        msg = msg.replace(new RegExp(path + '/?', 'g'), '');
                          ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //var/folders/F9/F9lleWHkHiiltRH5iZcuLk+++TI/-Tmp-/gulp-ruby-sass/?/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at /folderpath/web-starter-kit-master/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:46:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at removePaths (/folderpath/web-starter-kit-master/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:45:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/folderpath/web-starter-kit-master/node_modules    /gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:118:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into this (setting up WSK for the first time tonight too).

Looks like that was a bug that gulp-ruby-sass actually fixed a while ago:
https://github.com/rjm101/gulp-ruby-sass/commit/789d45f9b076781db652448a472357064a0f3e41

for whatever reason WSK doesn't have it yet in its node_modules dir.

I got this to work just by manually editing web-starter-kit-master/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js locally and making the above linked change.  I'm sure there's a more Proper way to deal with this but it's getting late and I'm losing patience :)